# How do I get back to my first spawning point?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a way to get back to my first spawning point in Minecraft 1.5? I've slept in other beds since then.

I'd prefer a solution that does not involve cheating, such as using some external tool.

Comment: What happens if you destory the last bed you slept in? I'll have to test this when I get home.

Comment: @Arkive > "The last bed could not be found."  And you default to your original spawn.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is anecdotal so someone will need to confirm this, but destroying or blocking the last bed you slept in will cause you to re-spawn at your original spawn point after you die.

Comment: Not anecdotal, this is the correct functionality. Destroying the bed you last slept in (you can place it again immediately, just do not sleep in it again) will allow you to /kill or just die in some way and return to the original spawn point.. Just make sure you have nothing on you :)

Comment: @James do you know if it checked for the destroyed bed when you use the compass, or will it point at the wrong location till you die?

Comment: I do not know, but I also do not trust the compass objects since where it led us too was about 100 units away from where we spawned when we died. Never investigated what happened, where I actually appeared was a better judge of spawn location to me :) Write down your coordinates of where you are, then die, and write down the spawn location. Do a nice long run to get some supplies if need be then you can make a trail. Or have someone run with you like I did :)

Answer (score 1):

You no longer need to kill yourself to get to your original spawn. Most recent Minecraft versions (don't have access to the wiki to check) have compasses that now point directly towards your original spawn.

This may make finding your bed harder, but will make finding default spawn as easy as crafting a compass and following the needle.

[Do compasses still point towards your spawn/bed?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28435/do-compasses-still-point-towards-your-spawn-bed)

Answer (score 0):

You can walk there, any other way like compasses won't work since they will point to your bed. I can't think of any other way except for creating a map of your world and walking back.

check this topic for more information
http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?f=1022&t=165779

edit: ok, seems to be the case that if you destroy your bed your spawn point is back at the original location.

Comment: Should get -1:  Compasses always point at your original spawn.

Comment: i haven't played in a week, but when i posted this answer, they pointed at your bed (if you had slept in it)

Comment: No, according to this question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28435/do-compasses-still-point-towards-your-spawn-bed