# Do compasses still point towards your spawn/bed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I use a compass it does not seem to point towards my bed. I have heard that now compasses point towards North. Is this true?

Comment: If you're compass doesn't point to your spawn, you may have a corrupted level.dat file resulting in the spawn point being set differently.

Comment: I thought the spawn was my bed (which it is) but it seems that the original spawn point is where compasses spawn.

Comment: "Where compasses spawn"???

Comment: hehe sorry. I meant where you originally spawn. I don't know what I was thinking!

Comment: haha I figured you did.  :)  Btw, have you slept in your bed?  They don't become your spawn point until you have.

Comment: Yes, I have slept in it for the past 20 days.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Compasses still point to the spawn point. Even with the `/sethome` plugins or if you've slept in a bed, it will remain pointing to the default spawn point.

> "Sleeping in a bed will change your respawn point, but will not change the original spawn point and location the compass points toward." – [Minecraft Wiki page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Compass)

Comment: Lame :( it would be more useful if it pointed to my bed.

Comment: It seems the comment on the Wiki was removed is this still accurate as I have a person SWEARING it doesn't.